# Replacing numbers in a string

Tags: java, string, numbers

I have a string of digits as follows:

```
String digits = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10";
```

I need to set the ones that are less than 5 to 0 and the remaining ones to 1.

I tried with for example

```
digits = digits.replaceAll("[56789]", "1");// etc.
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Tried the solutions that were already given on SO, I couldn't get them to work

If there actually is a question that can help me, please link it and I will delete this one.

**Solution**
return digits.replaceAll("[0-4]","0").replaceAll("[5-9]", "1");

This has worked for me, but when I write it separate it doesn't work.

Comment: Which other ways did you try? Do you want to replace digits or whole numbers (eg. should `44` be replaced by `00` or `1`)?

Comment: *But it doesn't seem to work* - care to provide an example?

Comment: @palpatin : if you found the answer you must accept the answer which helps you, so that others can find it helpful

Comment: @Manasi I've put what worked for me in the answer section, but as early as I can  accept my answer is in 2 days

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 digits =  digits.replaceAll("([0-4])", "0");
 digits =  digits.replaceAll("([5-9])", "1")
```

if 44 should not become 00

```
digits =digits.replaceAll("\\b([0-4]\\b)", "0");

digits =digits.replaceAll("\\b([5-9]\\b)", "1");
```

Comment: with the above 10 becomes 00

Comment: @Julio : Palpatin3 has not answered if he want to replace 44 as 00 or not. anyways updated the answer hope this will solve the issue

Comment: This has worked out for me in the end:
 return digits.replaceAll("[0-4]", "0").replaceAll("[5-9]", "1");

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
String digits = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10";
String result = Arrays.stream(digits.split(",\\s*"))// split with comma and spaces
        .map(Integer::valueOf)                      // parse your string to Integer
        .map(i ->  i > 0 && i < 5 ? "1" : "0")      // if condition is true return 1 else 0
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));         // collect the result in the end
```

**Outputs**

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: I get this error "reached end of file while parsing"

Comment: @Palpatin3 The error is not related with my solution, can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: This has worked out for me in the end:
return digits.replaceAll("[0-4]", "0").replaceAll("[5-9]", "1");

Answer (score 1):

Can't you convert the string array to an int array and do the job?

```
 String[] strArray = a.
 int[] intArray = new int[strArray.length];
 for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
     intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
     // Here you can implement your business logic
 }
```

And if you want to be an String, you can do:

```
Arrays.toString(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work

```
//At the top
import java.lang.StringBuffer;

String digits = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
StringBuffer dig = new StringBuffer(digits);
for(int p = 0; p < dig.length(); p++){
char h = dig.charAt(p);
if(Character.isDigit(h)){
    if(h < '5'){
      dig.setCharAt(p,'0');
    }
    else if(h >= '5'){
      dig.setCharAt(p,'1');
    }
}
}
digits = dig.toString();
System.out.println(digits);
```

StringBuffer provides mutable string like objects.

Answer (score 0):

return digits.replaceAll("[0-4]", "0").replaceAll("[5-9]", "1");

// This is the only way I found that worked for this situation.

Comment: somehow  digits =  digits.replaceAll("([0-4])", "0");
 digits =  digits.replaceAll("([5-9])", "1") didnt work for me